# diawi- app stuck and make dark icon on screen

Tags: ios, xcode, itunes

whenever i want to install application through diawi, it stuck in middle and make a dark spotted icon, and when i want to delete it, it is not deleting. someone tell me how can i delete these apps. i am posting the spotted image.  [image: app with dark spot]

Comment: you need to configure your project setting bundle identifier , i face similar problem and proper config. of project setting it works

Answer (score 0):

please build app with same certificates you have build app last.
**Try reinstall and let it install completely and then delete it.**